# How to test "Reset field spec" using capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I have Reset button on page which clear all forms fields. But how to write test to this feature in capybara ??

I tried this:

```
#view
<%= f.submit "Reset", :type => "reset", :id => "reset", :class => "btn btn-large" %>

#spec
fill_in 'wifi_name_zip', :with => "testzip"
find(:xpath,"//input[@type='reset']", "test").click

find_field('wifi_name_full_name').value.should be_blank
```

But i recieve:

```
 Failure/Error: find_field('wifi_name_full_name').value.should be_blank
   expected blank? to return true, got false
```

Comment: Is this using Javascript? Did you tag the examples with `:js`?

Comment: No. I dont use JS in project at all.

Comment: try `be_empty` instead `be_blank`